# Mostrar valores de un List en Labels

Tags: c#, windows-forms

Quiero mostrar los valores que obtengo de un consulta, los guardo en un 'List' pero no me muestra nada:

```
private void getValues2()
{
    List<string> list2 = new List<string>();
    cn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT  SUM(Qty) AS QTY FROM    tbl_Kanban GROUP BY Part_Num", cn);
    SqlDataReader leer;
    leer = cmd.ExecuteReader();
    while (leer.Read() == true)
    {      
        list2.Add(leer[0].ToString());
    }
    if (list2.Count > 0)
    {   

    }

    cn.Close();
}
```

Comment: hola.. que esperas mostrar y donde?? es como que toda esa parte falta...

Comment: Entiendo que la consulta la has probado y funciona. Que es lo que ocurre que la lista no tiene elementos?

Answer (score 1):

No te muestra nada porque simplemente estás almacenando los datos en una variable `list2`. Para mostrar los datos debes incluir los datos en un control dentro de un formulario.

Mira este ejemplo:

```
    private void getValues2()
    {
        List<string> list2 = new List<string>();
        cn.Open();
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT  SUM(Qty) AS QTY FROM    tbl_Kanban GROUP BY Part_Num", cn);
        SqlDataReader leer;
        leer = cmd.ExecuteReader();
        while (leer.Read() == true)
        {
            list2.Add(leer[0].ToString());
        }
        if (list2.Count > 0)
        {
            ShowData(list2);
        }
        cn.Close();
    }

    private void ShowData(List<string> data)
    {
        var form = new Form();
        var listbox = new ListBox();
        form.Controls.Add(listbox);
        listbox.Items.AddRange(data.ToArray());
        form.Show();
    }
```

El método `ShowData` recibe una lista de strings, crea un formulario, añade un control ListBox al formulario e incluye los datos de la lista en el ListBox. Por último muestra el formulario.

Answer (score 0):

Lo correcto sería que la función retorne la lista como respuesta:

```
private List<string> getValues2()
{
    cn.Open();
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("SELECT  SUM(Qty) AS QTY FROM tbl_Kanban GROUP BY Part_Num", cn);
    SqlDataReader leer = cmd.ExecuteReader();

    List<string> lista = new List<string>();
    while(leer.Read())
    {
        lista.Add(leer[0].ToString());
    }

    cn.Close();

    return lista;
}
```

Entonces despues en el `form` usarías:

```
List<string> lista = getValues2();

foreach(var item in lista)
{
    ListBox1.Items.Add(item);
}
```

No sé si `getValues2()` lo defines dentro de una clase o en el mismo `form`, pero la idea es separar responsabilidades, por un lado obtienes los datos y por otro asignas estos al `ListBox`.

Si esa función está en una clase deberas crear la instancia para invocar su funcionalidad.